# How to transform the data in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, syntax, rule

Consider the following data:

```
datatest = 
  Join[RandomReal[{2, 3}, {5, 2}], 
   Table[{"something" <> ToString[i], "another" <> ToString[i]}, {i, 
     1, 5, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 1}], 2];
```

The description of its columns is given by

```
meanings = {"val_x", "val_y", "Something", "Something", "mom_x"};
```

I would like to multiply the columns containing "val_" by 0.01, the columns containing "mom_" by 0.001, and leave unchanged the other columns. In reality, the true data contains hundreds of such columns and thousands of rows, so it would be good to have an automatic way of doing this using patterns. I may define the transformation rule, say, `If[StringContainsQ[str,"val_"]==True,0.01]`, but I do not know how to apply this rule to the list in the form `transformation&/@datatest`. Could you please help me?

Comment: `{0.01, 0.01, 1, 1, 0.001} # & /@ datatest` ? or `{#1/100, #2/100, #3, #4, #5/1000} & @@@ datatest`

Comment: @Syed : this rule would be very inconvenient if `datatest` is made of hundreds of columns. I need a pattern of the transformation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I see what you are trying to do now.

Comment: `f = If[StringContainsQ[#, "val_"], 0.01, 
   If[StringContainsQ[#, "mom_"], 0.001, 1]] &` and `(f /@ meanings) # & /@ datatest` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the data:

```
datatest = 
  Join[RandomReal[{2, 3}, {5, 2}], 
   Table[{"something" <> ToString[i], "another" <> ToString[i]}, {i, 
     1, 5, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 1}], 2];
meanings = {"val_x", "val_y", "Something", "Something", "mom_x"};
```

We first need to determine in which columns "val_" and "mom_" appear:

```
posval = Position[meanings, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "val_" ~~ __]];
posmom = Position[meanings, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "mom_" ~~ __]];
```

Now we can multiply the corresponding columns with the matching factors:

```
datatest[[All, Flatten[posval]]] *= 0.01;
datatest[[All, Flatten[posmom]]] *= 0.001;
```

This results in:

```
datatest // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Taking the idea from @Syed's comment:

```
datatest = Join[RandomReal[{2, 3}, {5, 2}], 
  Table[{"something" <> ToString[i], "another" <> ToString[i]}, {i, 1, 5, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 1}], 2]
meanings = {"val_x", "val_y", "Something", "Something", "mom_x"};
```

```
transf = Table[Which[
   StringContainsQ[col, "val_"], 0.01,
   StringContainsQ[col, "mom_"], 0.001,
   True, 1
   ], {col, meanings}]
result = transf # & /@ datatest

result // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OP's example input:

```
datatest = 
  Join[RandomReal[{2, 3}, {5, 2}], 
   Table[{"something" <> ToString[i], "another" <> ToString[i]}, {i, 
     1, 5, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 1}], 2];
 meanings = {"val_x", "val_y", "Something", "Something", "mom_x"};
```

---

**TLDR**: You can use `Dataset` to construct a dataset `DatatestSet` and then specify a list of transformations for the columns you want to transform and then use `DatatestSet[All,transformations]`

---

**Note**: I am not an expert in datasets, I just noticed that the solution below seems to work and that the syntax seems to be coherent with the documentation on `Dataset`.

---

Your `datatest` list and `meanings` seem similar to [datasets](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/45-datasets.html) in Mathematica so I wanted to add a solution that uses `Dataset`.

First, consider constructing the dataset

```
DatatestSet=Dataset[AssociationThread[meanings,#]&/@datatest];
```

Then, specify the list of columns that will be transformed

```
valColumns=Select[StringMatchQ["val_"~~___]]@meanings;

momColumns=Select[StringMatchQ["mom_"~~___]]@meanings;
```

Define a multiplication function for convenience (optional)

```
mulFun[p_][x_]:=p*x;
```

Define the list of transformations that will be performed on the specified columns.

```
transformations=Join[Thread[valColumns->mulFun[0.01]],Thread[momColumns->mulFun[0.001]]]
```

Displaying the original dataset in order to compare with the transformed dataset below

[image: input]

The transformed dataset :

```
DatatestSet[All,transformations]
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to show a solution similar to userrand's:

```
datatest =
  Join[RandomReal[{2, 3}, {5, 2}], 
   Table[{"something" <> ToString[i], "another" <> ToString[i]}, {i, 1, 5, 1}], RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 1}], 2];

meanings = {"val_x", "val_y", "Something", "Another", "mom_x"};

asc = AssociationThread[meanings, #] & /@ datatest;

pv = Flatten @ Position[meanings, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, "val*"] &)];
pm = Flatten @ Position[meanings, _String?(StringMatchQ[#, "mom*"] &)];

res =
  Query[All,
    Join[
     Thread[pv -> (# * 0.01 &)],
     Thread[pm -> (# * 0.001 &)]]] @ asc;


res // Dataset
```

[image]

Or, alternatively,

```
Values[res] // MatrixForm
```

[image]